# How can I use camera in raspberry 64 bit

Tags: raspicam, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-buster

- raspberry pi 4(ram 4g)
- raspberry buster 64 bit
- pi camera

I tried and knew that raspistill or pi camera doesn’t work in 64 bit os.
(64 bit os is beta version so It doesn’t support it)

Is there any solution to use camera on 64 bit os?
what I want is only capture the image!

It is okay that I can’t use pi camera.
I want to know that is there a way to use USB camera or other camera on 64 bit on

Comment: There is NO "raspberry buster 64 bit" - there was an incomplete beta test.

Answer (score 1):

You need connect your camera to the camera socket on the rpi. Then enter the terminal and write this:

```
raspistill -o Desktop/image.jpg
```

You can change Desktop.

And its saving photo.

If you want control your camera with Python:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
sleep(5)
camera.stop_preview()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Does this work on 64bit raspberry pi OS as specifically asked in the question?

Comment: raspberry pi 64 bit doesn’t support raspistill or pi camera.... so I asked this question

Comment: I have just installed 64 bit for raspberry pi 4 and cannot find the camera enable in raspi-config. This seems strange!

Comment: Not being able to install raspistill makes me think they have not got around to supporting this in 64 bit yet.
    r@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install raspistill
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package raspistill
    r@raspberrypi:~ $

Comment: @Robin please see my answer below, it is supported, just a huge new range of commands.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't get the raspistill product installed. I don't think it will **ever** be supported as there seems to be a range of libraries for the 64 bit version and probably has been abandoned after "Buster". Tom's hardware goes into it in more details:

https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/use-raspberry-pi-camera-with-bullseye

However, just in case that get's lost or deleted, some interesting commands are:

```
libcamera-hello
```

Gives a preview screen

```
libcamera-jpeg -o test.jpg
```

Takes a single picture with the file mentioned.

And a 10 second video:

```
libcamera-vid -t 10000 -o test.h264
```

Note I did not have to enable, add or install any software. Not even the legacy mode in the command line raspi-config.
What it does mean is that if you have legacy software that does use raspistill then it won't work and will need to be rewritten.

Comment: The legacy camera stuff is NOT supported with the 64-bit OSes. Enabling it will disable your modern camera. Use the `libcamera-*` programs they work (and follow the `raspistill`/`raspivid` options where applicable).

Comment: @Dougie A recommended library is as follows: https://qengineering.eu/install-gstreamer-1.18-on-raspberry-pi-4.html